# Undefined property: App\Controllers\Courtyard::$uri

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass the second segment of a URI from the controller to view, using this code:

```
         $data = [
             'meta_title' => 'My Title',
             'title' => 'Real Title',
             'urlSegment' => $this->uri->segment('2'),
                 ];
```

But I keep getting this error:
**Undefined property: App\Controllers\Courtyard::$uri**

Do you know what I`m doing wrong here?

Comment: [Have you read the official documentation?](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#the-current-uri)

Comment: Which version of CI you are using?

Comment: I`m  using version 4

Comment: did you create an uri instance? e.g.: `$uri = service('uri');`

Comment: $this->request->uri->getSegment(1) was the correct sintax